# How to solve the differential equation: $y'=\sqrt{|y|}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

While trying to solve the differential equation: $y'=\sqrt{|y|}$. I got confused how to deal with the absolute value. I want to draw a sketch for the direction field for that equation, and see for what initial values does this equation fulfill the conditions of the existence and uniqueness Theorem.

I tried to do the integral according to the sign, depends if $(y>0)$ or $(y<0)$. but I'm still not sure if my result is right.

result that I got:

- while $y>0$ : $y=({\frac{x}{2}+c})^{2}$
- while $y<0$ : $y=({-\frac{x}{2}+c})^{2}$

if that's the case, Its hard for me to imagine the Direction field by these two equations, because they are always above axis: $x$. How does it look? any hints?

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Solving $y′ = \sqrt{|y|}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319137/solving-y-sqrty)

Comment: Andrew its not exacrly the same since im asking about the direction field.

Answer (score 2):

For the $y<0$ case your DE is evaluated incorrectly:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{-y}$$

$$(-y)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$

$$-2\sqrt{-y}=x+c$$

$$-4y=(x+c)^2$$

$$y=-\frac{(x+c)^2}{4}$$

This should hopefully help you to visualize the direction field now. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Cool! What program did you use?

Comment: Wolfram's Mathematica

Comment: one last question, does the solutions here cross the solution $y=0$? , I think yes because the conditions of Existence and Uniqueness Theorem are not fulfilled. right?

Answer (score 0):

for $y>0$
$$(y)^{-\frac{1}{2}}y'=1$$
$$2y^{\frac{1}{2}}=x+c$$
$$y^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}(x+c)$$
$$y=\frac{1}{4}(x+c)^2=(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{c}{2})^2=(\frac{x}{2}+k)^2$$
this answer same your answer

when the $y<0$
$$(-y)^{-\frac{1}{2}}y'=1$$
the solution is
$$y=-(\frac{x}{2}+k)^2$$

Comment: Its hard for me to imagine the Direction field by these two equations, because they are always above axis: $x$. is that the case ?

Comment: The DE in the question is not the same as $(y)^{-\frac{1}{2}}y'=-1$ for the case when $y<0$.

Comment: @IanMiller ok, thanks , I have corrected it