# Are these equations "properly" defined differential equations? (finite duration solutions to diff. eqs.)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, singular-solution, finite-duration

**Are these equations properly defined differential equations?**

*Modifications were made to a deleted question to re-focus it. I am trying to find out if there exists any exact/accurate/non-approximated mathematical framework to work with physics under the assumption that* **phenomena have finite ending-times,** *instead of solutions that at best vanishes at infinity.*

---

*Intro*

**Definition 1 - Solutions of finite-duration:** the solution $y(t)$ becomes exactly zero at a finite time $T<\infty$ by its own dynamics and stays there forever after $(t\geq T\Rightarrow y(t)=0)$. So, they are different of just a piecewise section made by any arbitrarily function multiplied by rectangular function: **it must solve the differential equation in the whole domain.** *(Here I just pick the shorter name its look more natural to me for several I found: "finite-time", "finite-time-convergence", "finite-duration", "time-limited", "compact-supported time", "finite ending time", "singular solutions", "finite extinction time", among others).*

Recently, in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4423493/909869) I figure out that the following **autonomous scalar ODE**:
$$\dot{y}=-\sqrt[n]{y} \tag{Eq. 1}\label{Eq. 1}$$
Could stand the finite-duration solutions, for any real-valued $n>1$ and positive ending time $T>0$:
$$ y(t)=\left[\frac{(n-1)}{n}\left(T-t\right)\right]^{\frac{n}{(n-1)}}\,\theta(T-t)\equiv y(0)\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{t}{T}+\left|1-\frac{t}{T}\right|\right)\right]^{\frac{n}{(n-1)}} \tag{Eq. 2}\label{Eq. 2}$$
with $\theta(t)$ the standard [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

But later, working with the solution of \eqref{Eq. 2} I figure out that if I take its derivative I will end with:
$$\begin{array}{r c l}
\dot{y} & = & -\left[\frac{(n-1)}{n}\left(T-t\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{(n-1)}}\,\theta(T-t)+\underbrace{\left[\frac{(n-1)}{n}\left(T-t\right)\right]^{\frac{n}{(n-1)}}\,\delta(T-t)}_{=\,0\,\text{due}\,(x-a)^n\delta(x-a)=0} \\
& = & -\left[\frac{(n-1)}{n}\left(T-t\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{(n-1)}}\,\theta(T-t) \\
& = & -\frac{n}{(n-1)}\frac{1}{(T-t)}y(t)
\end{array}$$
Which implies that the solutions $y(t)$ are also solving the **non-autononous scalar ODE** (is time-variant since the time $t$ is explicitely involved):
$$\dot{y}+\frac{n}{(n-1)}\cdot \frac{y}{(T-t)} = 0 \tag{Eq. 3}\label{Eq. 3}$$

This last equation of \eqref{Eq. 3} resembles very much this [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4410321/909869) were I found that the finite duration solution:
$$z(t)=\exp\left(\frac{t}{(t-1)}\right)\cdot\theta(1-t) \tag{Eq. 4}\label{Eq. 4}$$
can solve the equation:
$$\dot{z}+\frac{z}{(1-t)^2} = 0,\quad z(0)=1\tag{Eq. 5}\label{Eq. 5}$$

So I started to try another finite-duration solutions to see if their differential equations follows the same "trend" of having terms $(T-t)$ on it: which means that an standard integration constant is becoming part of the differential equation as its finite ending time $T$.

---

*Main analysis*

On [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4408245/909869) is found that similarly for equations \eqref{Eq. 3}:
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{4}(2-t)^2\theta(2-t) \tag{Eq. 13}\label{Eq. 13}$$
is a finite duration solution to:
$$\dot{x}=-\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{|x|},\,x(0)=1\tag{Eq. 14}\label{Eq. 14}$$
so I will modify this solution to see what happens:
$$q(t) = \frac{1}{4}(2-t)^2\cos(20\,t)\,\theta(2-t)\tag{Eq. 6}\label{Eq. 6}$$
which can be verified is solves the equation:
$$\ddot{q}+\frac{4}{(2-t)}\cdot \dot{q}+\left(400+\frac{6}{(2-t)^2}\right)\cdot q = 0,\quad q(0)=1,\,\,\dot{q}(0)=-1\tag{Eq. 7}\label{Eq. 7}$$

Again, on \eqref{Eq. 7} there terms $(2-t) \cong (T-t)$ indicating that there exists solutions that are behaving like finite duration solutions (see [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F4+%28-2+%2B+t%29%5E2+cos%2820+t%29+UnitStep%282+-+t%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D) of \eqref{Eq. 6}).

But these "construction" of making finite duration solutions where these **two conditions** are met:

1. The differential equation support the zero solution, and
2. The differential equation also has at least one [singular point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution#Failure_of_uniqueness) in time $t=T$ where $x(T)=\dot{x}(T)=0$

both mentioned on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4411118/909869), becomes less obvious where more than one variable is considered. Let think and a slight modification to the function of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4333286/909869):

$$U(t,x) = \exp\left(1-\frac{1}{(1-(x-t)^2)}\right)\theta(1-(x-t)^2) \tag{Eq. 8}\label{Eq. 8}$$

it will show to be compact supported in space as it moves in the time variable, fulfilling the standard wave equation with a velocity $c=1$:
$$\left(\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\right)U(t,x)=0 \overset{c=1}{\Rightarrow} U_{tt}-U_{xx}=0 \tag{Eq. 9}\label{Eq. 9}$$

Here the partial equation doesn't show the term $(T-t)$, but it does make sense if the [countour plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=contour+plot+e%281-1%2F%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29%29*unitstep%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29) of \eqref{Eq. 6} is viewed:

[image: Eq 8 plots]

It is only compacted-supported in space and it is still never-ending in time.

But if I test this modified version of \eqref{Eq. 8} mixed with the terms of \eqref{Eq. 2}:

$$E(t,x) = U(t,x)\cdot \frac{1}{4}(2-t)^2\,\theta(2-t) = \exp\left(1-\frac{1}{(1-(x-t)^2)}\right)\theta(1-(x-t)^2)\cdot\frac{1}{4}(2-t)^2\,\theta(2-t) \tag{Eq. 10}\label{Eq. 10}$$

where this time it can be seen in its [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=contour+plot+e%5E%281-1%2F%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29%29*unitstep%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29*1%2F4+%282+-+t%29%5E2*UnitStep%282+-+t%29) that is indeed behaving as also a finite duration solution in time:

[image: Eq 10 plots]

It could be verified that is solves the equation:
$$E_{tt}-E_{xx}+\frac{4}{(2-t)}E_{t}+\frac{6}{(2-t)^2}E = 0 \tag{Eq. 11}\label{Eq. 11}$$
within the domain \eqref{Eq. 10} is different from zero (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Be%5E%281-1%2F%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29%29*1%2F4%28t-2%29%5E2%2C%7Bt%2C2%7D%5D-D%5Be%5E%281-1%2F%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29%29*1%2F4%28t-2%29%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C2%7D%5D%2B4%2F%282-t%29*D%5Be%5E%281-1%2F%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29%29*1%2F4%28t-2%29%5E2%2C%7Bt%2C1%7D%5D%2B6%2F%282-t%29%5E2*e%5E%281-1%2F%281-%28x-t%29%5E2%29%29*1%2F4%282-t%29%5E2)). So again the terms $(T-t)$ are required for having finite-duration solutions.

I beforehand know that some of these functions should be defined piecewise because has a undefined value, as example:
$$ f(t) = \begin{cases} \exp\left(\frac{t}{(t-1)}\right),\quad t < 1 \\
                        0, \qquad t\geq 1 \end{cases} \tag{Eq. 12}\label{Eq. 12}$$
instead of the one-line version of \eqref{Eq. 4}, so I ask you now to forgive this shortcut for now: the functions still continuous on these points and for me are easy to work with them finding their differential equations on this way (I have a extended discussion of this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4382260/909869)), but if this annoying you, please just assume it is defined piecewise such as the function is zero in the undefined point.

This comment is important, since I want to focus the discussion in the other singularities that appears on these equations (and sometimes the point could be coincident), and are the discontinuities on the differential equations due the terms $(T-t)$.

---

**The questions**

**1) Are all these differential equations with terms $(T-t)$ "well-defined" as differential equations?**

**2) Which are the name of this kind of differential equations?** (noting here there are ODEs and PDEs with these terms - hope there are any references)

**3) Does this $(T-t)$ terms on the denominator make these differential equation Non-Lipschitz?** Here looking for parallels with the papers by V. T. Haimo:  [Finite Time Differential Equations](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4048613) and [Finite Time Controllers](https://doi.org/10.1137/0324047).

**4) Does this $(T-t)$ terms on the denominator make possible the existence of solutions of finite duration?** Remembering here that solutions of finite duration don't fulfill uniqueness (see the recently cited papers for better explanation), a singularity in my opinion makes sense since there are multiple values rising from a single point, which is similar with traditional mistakes made when dividing by zero - but formally speaking, I have no idea of what it is happening.

---

**Motivation**

I am trying to find a mathematical framework to work with dynamical systems under the assumption: **the system achieves an end in finite time**, which seems really logical to me through daily life experience, but I have found this is really messy when it is translated to math (I still didn't find a related framework).

Current physics solutions at best "vanishes at infinity", which is not exact but fairly good for almost every possible application, so good, that I have had discussions with many people that affirm as true that movement last forever, which at least under the assumption that thermal noise is Gaussian, you can say if it still moving (neither if it has stopped), since already all the information is lost: Gaussian distribution is the [Maximum entropy probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution) for a phenomena with finite mean and finite power. Don't meaning the assumption of never ending movement is wrong, but affirming is true is indeed false (see the comments of this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/698023/modeling-friction-with-non-lipschitz-odes-pendulum-example) to a more detailed discussion applied to the pendulum movement).

This subtle distinction is seen for example, in the [Galton board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton_board) toy, where many people affirm that somehow order have risen from chaos, due the appearance of the Normal Distribution, when the right interpretation is that all the information of the path each ball have take when falling is already lost, and the Gaussian distribution is the maximum possible disordered way of been for this system (to have an intuition of why there is a lobe in the middle, take a look to [Concentration inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality)).

But nowadays there is a lot of theoretical physics squeezing their models to the very last drop and many counter-intuitive things are reaching mainstream: many Youtube videos talking about the "nonexistence" of time (is an illusion), and also many videos about the impossibility of current physics laws to determine "the direction of the arrow of time", and I would like to know if any of this things is due current models are not aware of the effects of keeping the assumption that phenomena have finite ending times.

As example, in all the differential equations of this question there indeed a clue of which way the time is considered to be flowing (due the term $(T-t)$), and for the solutions, going backwards in time will lead to spontaneous rise from zero (being zero from a non-zero meassure interval in time).

I know that current models are on the way they are because the models were designed to keep holding uniqueness of solutions, which if not could lead to a lot of struggles (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426755/909869) some of this issues with the Norton's Dome example).

But I also know now that for the existence of solutions of finite duration uniqueness of solutions must be abandoned, and I would like to know if this were known by physicists, if the current models would still been having their current formulations (to keep this on perspective, main models have about a hundred years old, and the first papers about finite duration solutions I have found are from 1985).

And maybe because they are "relativately new", I only found these finite duration solutions on control theory papers (where they started assuming a high-knowledge background from the reader), and every book I find on differential equation keep their analysis tied to uniqueness, so they don't touch this topic. With this, any related book reference will be useful.

---

*Answering two firsts comments by @Desura*

Some user named @Desura mentioned the existence of the [Frobenius method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) and the [Fuchs' theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchs%27_theorem) for solving differential equations of the form $u''+\frac{p(t)}{t}u'+\frac{q(t)}{t^2}u=0$, and also what is a [Regular singular point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point). On all these pages you can see differential equations that really resemble the ones I have displayed above, so very much for share it.

I would like to comment why I think these kind of methods aren't able to find solutions of finite duration by "themselves", and also how I think I am already using them through Wolfram-Alpha.

On the mentioned papers by Vardia T. Haimo (1985) [Finite Time Controllers](https://doi.org/10.1137/0324047) and [Finite Time Differential Equations](https://doi.org/10.1109/CDC.1985.268832), where only scalar autonomous ODEs of 1st and 2nd order are studied ($x'=G(x)$ or $x''=G(x',x)$), then by assuming without lost of generality that $T=0$, and also assuming that the right-hand-side of the ODE is at least class $C^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$, the author mentioned that:

*"One notices immediately that finite time differential equations cannot be Lipschitz at the origin. As all solutions reach zero in finite time, there is non-uniqueness of solutions through zero in backwards time. This, of course, violates the uniqueness condition for solutions of Lipschitz differential equations."*

So, if the author is right, **NO Lipschitz 1st or 2nd order scalar autonomous ODEs could stand solutions of finite duration**, so classic linear ODEs are discarded.

But reaching zero in finite time have also another consequence, and is that also are discarded classical solutions through Power Series which are **analytical in the whole domain**, since there exist a non-zero measure compact set of points identical to zero, the only analytical function that could support this matching is the zero function, due the [Identity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Because of this last paragraph, is why I believe that a method that find the coefficients for a function of the form $\sum_k a_k(T-t)^k$ aren't able to describe a finite duration solution "alone", which is a traditional method for finding solution to ODEs (as the method shown by @Desura).

But fortunately, being analytic in a piecewise part of the time domain and zero on the part "looks like" working if the **two restrictions** are met (now labeled after \eqref{Eq. 7}), as they are used for finding the solution of the now labeled \eqref{Eq. 14}, which is demonstrated on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4408259/909869). Here is where I am using the traditional ways of finding solutions to differential equations, to find the "non-zero section".

But How this "construction" by "stitching solutions" is formally working, or if they are being or not formal solutions to the differential equations is something I don´t know (I am "highly abusing" of an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4411118/909869) without any formal prove - but because it "make sense"), neither when we have to "choose" one solution or another (since there are multiple options now - at least with this "construction": the full solutions, the finite duration alternative, or the other piece that rise spontaneously from zero). This is why I am looking for a framework, but because as requirement **uniqueness must be left aside**, traditional books in differential equations don't touch this kind of solutions.

Even so, on the mentioned papers of V. T. Haimo, this kind of solutions aren't studied at all, and more interestingly, there are given a 2nd order ODE example where is shown that depending on its parameters, the differential equation could allow having finite duration solutions, but outside "this restriction" the solutions are not of finite duration (unfortunately no exact solution is given).

**Last update**

I have just found the following papers under the term **sublinear damping** that shows example in physics of equations really similar to one showed on the papers by V. T. Haimo, containing terms of the form $\text{sgn}(\dot{x})|\dot{x}|^\alpha$ which are achieving **finite extinction times** without having the form of the [Frobenius method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) with displaced terms $(T-t)$:

- ["A note on the dynamics of an oscillator in the presence of strong friction" - H.Amann & J.I.Diaz](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0362-546X(03)00221-9)
- ["A conservation law with spatially localized sublinear damping" - Christophe Besse & Sylvain Ervedoza](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.anihpc.2019.03.002)
- ["Behavior of Solutions of Second-Order Differential Equations with Sublinear Damping" - J. Karsai & J. R. Graef](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11072-005-0048-0)

I don't know if maybe after knowing their exact solutions, they could be transformed on differential equations similar of the asked on the main question, as it was done for carrying \eqref{Eq. 2} to become into \eqref{Eq. 3} (I believe implying with this their decaying is exponential $\propto t^{-\beta},\,\beta>0$ for some $\beta$), maybe it could be proved with what is shown on the papers. Other similar examples were listed into this [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4433223/909869).

Comment: You might be interested in studying first the following class of linear $n$-th order ODEs $f^{(n)}(z) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p_i(z)f^{(i)}(z) = 0$ with initial data at $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ and coefficients $p_i(z)$ which are meromorphic around $z_0$ for all $i \in \{0,1,...,n-1\}$. Then the point $z_0$ can be classified in three ways : an ordinary point, a regular singular point and a fully irregular point.

Comment: The existence and uniqueness theory breaks only in the fully irregular case. In the regular singular case, solutions with singularity at $z_0$ can exist but this is not always the case and it will depend only on the poles of the $p_i(z)$'s (look for Frobenius Theorem, Fuchs Theorem or Fuchsian Differential Equations). Please note that your equation (7) has a regular singular point at $z_0 = 2$.

Comment: @Desura thanks you very much for your interesting comments. I didn't know before about the [Frobenius method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) neither about [Regular singular point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point). I will add, bacause of extension, what I think into the question during the next hour.

Comment: @Desura I have just upload on the question my comments. Hope you can elaborate after read them. Beforehand, thanks you very much.

Comment: It seems to me that the sentence *phenomena have finite ending-times* is ambiguous. For example, the autonomous ODE $y^\prime = y^2$ has solutions exploding to infinity in a finite time. So formally, the system has a finite ending time. Is it something that you regard as a phenomenon that has a finite ending-time? IMHO, I think that you should revisit your question by trying to precisely define what is still fuzzy. That will help yourself to understand in more detail the topic... And then facilitate answers!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have added a definition now, thanks you very much for commenting.

Comment: @Joako I would rather say if I understand you well, that the solution is always vanishing in an interval $[T , T+ a)$ with $a \gt 0$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net what I am saying is that for a continuous real-valued solution $y(t)$ defined on the whole domain $\mathbb{R}$, the solution is such as exist an ending time $T<\infty$ such that for every $t>T,\, y(t)=0$ **due the dynamics of the system** (not just an arbitrary piecewise section). I believe this can be understood through the question examples.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Maybe I am using mistaken names due my lack of background, and surely there are grammar mistakes since I am not a native English speaker. Since this is different from what you are saying (it needs $a\to\infty$), I am open to suggestions for explainning this better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Are all these differential equations with terms $(T-t)$ "well-defined" as differential equations?**

Their well-posenedness will depend on the multiplicity of the singularities. You will need to check whether the singular points are regular or irregular. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point. You may also check the Frobenius method which will be particularly useful for some of your differential equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method.

**2) Which are the name of this kind of differential equations?**

They are commonly referred to as **singular differential equations**.

**3) Does this $(T-t)$ terms on the denominator make these differential equation Non-Lipschitz?**

Of course, they make it non-Lipschitz. A necessary condition for being Lipschitz is to be continuous and $1/(T-t)$ is not continuous at $t=T$.

**4) Does this $(T-t)$ terms on the denominator make possible the existence of solutions of finite duration?**

It may but that may not be the best solution to do so. You gave the example in Eq. 4 and Eq. 5.

Comment: *Of course, they make it non-Lipschitz. A necessary condition for being Lipschitz is to be continuous and $1/(T−t)$ is not continuous at $t=T$*. The problem is not so much that $1/(T−t)$ is not continuous at $t=T$. It is that it is not even defined! However $t \mapsto 1/(T−t)$ is locally Lipschitz for any $t$ where the map is defined. Which is enough to ensure that the ODE has a unique maximal solution at any point $t_0 \neq T$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yeah that's correct. I will update my post when I get back home.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer!.. I found now this wiki about [Singular solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution#Failure_of_uniqueness) where even the "stitch solution construction" is used. There is explained, since the singular point is required to fail uniqueness, that the answer to part (4) is indeed true, is the singularity given by the term $(T-t)$ which makes possible to have finite duration solution. But also, having a singular solution or a Regular singular solution don't grant the differential equation is having solutions of finite duration, since are other...

Comment: (...) other kinds of singular solutions. Now I believe that the **two conditions**: (i) the trivial zero function is a solution, (ii) exist a singular point at time $T<\infty$ such as $y(T)=\dot{y}(T)=0$, are mandatory to have finite duration solutions... but I can prove it, neither know if they are sufficient - or maybe less is required.

Comment: @Joako That's an interesting problem.

Comment: The first condition is trivial to verify, but I tried in past questions to review How to figure out if an equation, like Eq. 11 as example, from it description, if it has a point that fulfill condition (ii) but unsuccessfully: I don't know if it could have points that aren't singular that fulfill the condition $x(T)=\dot{x}(T)=0$. Also, there are examples where the solution is smooth, so all derivatives are going to zero at $t=T$ as it could happen in solutions like Eq. 4 or smooth bump functions, but this don't going to happen in solutions that aren't smooth as in Eq. 13.

Comment: On the papers by V. T. Haimo other requirements are explored, but since there are studied only scalar autonomous systems of 1st and 2nd order ODEs, I don't know if the same method could be extended to analyse general singular solutions.

Comment: @Joako there has been a lot of work on the topic in control theory for finite convergence of control systems and the like. This has been well-studied.

Comment: As electrical engineer, I have basic knowledge in control theory, and I have read a few papers related to **finite time convergence** but unfortunately, for me, they are very abstract (so far, it have been hard to find closed form/exact solutions examples - also they mix solutions that converges with solutions that diverges). This differently from the websites you site, where with basic knowledge of differential equations you can understand what it is been explained. In the same line, proving that the **two conditions suffice** will made it much easier to understand and work with (I hope).

Comment: You will almost never find explicit solutions to differential equations. Most of them are not explicitly solvable only the simple ones are. What is important are the qualitative properties (e.g. stability) and certain quantitative properties (e.g. a bound on the finite convergence time).

Comment: I believe I have been lucky this time, after finding Eq. 2 (which can be an approximation to many kinds of different decays), I have been able to made many solutions to later find their differential equations and see how they behave, and it result to have a known and not-too-abstract framework like the Frobenius method, which at least for me, it see much easier to work with than Lyapunov theory (at least from what I have been able to understand from the papers). Hope you give a chance to prove if the 2 conditions suffice, or if could exists non-singular points that fulfill (ii), and include it

Comment: I find already that $g(x)=\cos(x)-1$ will fulfill $g(0)=g'(0)=0$ without being a singular point, so it will be needed to condition (ii) to be a singular point in time.

Comment: What is $g(x)$?

Comment: @KBS it was just an example function that fulfill $g(T)=g'(T)=0$... the first time I talked about the two conditions I didn't mentioned anything about it has to be a singular point, as I did later talking in this trend of comments... and now I believe this restricted version is the right form: at least for a diff. ec. of the form $a(t)f''(t)+p(t)f'(t)+q(t)f(t)=0$, if there exist a time $T$ such as $f(T)=f'(T)=0$ the equation becomes $a(T)f''(T)=0$, so without taking for granted the value of the second derivative, it is going to be a pole in the point because of $a(t)$,....

Comment: @KBS so at least in the Frobenius Method the point also requires to be a Regular singular point. Later I note that if an arbitrary function $g(t)$ such as at a point $t*$ happen to be $g'(t*)=0$, then I can built other function $s(t)=g(t)-g(t*)$ which will always fulfill $s(t*)=s'(t*)=0$ so having that property by itself is quite general, so, without formal prove, I think that to be a singular point is required.

Comment: Now I figure out is a must to have a singular point, otherwise uniqueness couldn't be violated... sorry about my related confussion.

Comment: In a general framework for a 2nd order scalar diff. eq. $y''=F(y',y)$ if condition (i) is fullfiled I will have that $F(0,0)=0$. Now, if there is a point $t=T,\,|T|<\infty$ where $y(T)=y'(T)=0$ then $y''(T)=F(y'(T),y(T))=F(0,0)=0$, so if additionally, the point $T$ is singular, so uniqueness could be broken, all conditions for stich solutions are made. With this, I believe the "strict two conditions" (now corrected above), for having a solutions of finite duration are sufficient, Is this right? (maybe less is required, since mentioned papers does a different analysis)

Comment: That sounds correct to me. You indeed need non-uniqueness of solutions to have that.

Comment: Even if the two conditions are being "sufficient", from the paper of V. T. Haimo looks like sometimes are not necessarily both required: in her analysis she found that for the differential equation:
$$\ddot{x}=−\text{sgn}(x)|x|^a−\text{sgn}(\dot{x})|\dot{x}|^b$$
 if the parameters are such $0<b<1$ and $\frac{b}{2−b}<a$ then there exist solutions of finite duration. Here, completely different from the **two conditions** analysis I did above: I don't know how to apply the (ii) condition since there is no clue of what is the finite ending time (different from the poles in the Frobenius method)

Comment: @KBS I hope you can update your answer as you tell to mathcounterexamples.net, including your last comments. It would be great to share it in a concise way on other forums. Again thanks you very much for your help and pattience.

Answer (score 2):

**Introduction**

In what follows, we'll only consider first-order [Ordinary differential equations (ODE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) defined as $$y^\prime(t) = f(t, y(t))$$ where $f : U \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $U\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is an open subset.

According to [Peano existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem), the [Initial value Problem (IVP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem)

$$\begin{cases}
y^\prime(t) &= f(t, y(t))\\
y(t_0) &= y_0\end{cases}$$ where $(t_0,x_0) \in U$ has at least one [maximal solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Solutions).

Interestingly, the solution **may not be global** as can be seen with the case
$$\begin{cases}
y^\prime(t) &= y^2(t)\\
y(1) &= 1\end{cases}$$ that explodes to infinity in a finite time. By the way **an interesting** theorem states that either the solution of such ODEs is global, either it reaches points outside of any compact in a finite time.

**The solution may also not be unique** as can be seen with the  [following example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239284/can-a-differential-equation-have-non-unique-solutions)$$\begin{cases}
y^\prime(t) &= \sqrt{\lvert y(t) \rvert }\\
y(0) &= 0\end{cases}$$

However, as stated by [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), the IVP $$\begin{cases}
y^\prime(t) &= f(t, y(t))\\
y(t_0) &= y_0\end{cases}$$ has a unique maximal solution for any $(t_0,y_0) \in U$ providing that $f(t, y)$ is locally Lipschitz in $y$ for any $y_0$. This is in particular the case if $f$ is continuously differentiable.

**Solutions of finite duration**

So coming back to your question, you're expecting to get solutions $y$ defined in an open interval $(a,b)$ for which $y(t) = 0$ for $t \ge T$ where $T \in (a,b)$ and... **that are not always vanishing**. That would be too simple.

You can't get such solutions according to Picard–Lindelöf theorem if $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $y$ around $y(T)$.

But you don't need to have $t-T$ in the denominator of some term of the ODE to get the finite duration phenomena. $$\begin{cases}
y^\prime(t) &= \sqrt{\lvert y(t) \rvert }\\
y(0) &= 0\end{cases}$$ is a good example for that!

**I know that this doesn't answer to your precise 4 questions. However, I think that this provides you with a much global way to study the finite duration topic you raised.**

*Interesting would be to answer following question.*

Suppose that you have an autonomous IVP $$\begin{cases}
y^\prime(t) &= f(y(t))\\
y(t_0) &= y_0\end{cases}$$ where $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, continuously differentiable for $y \neq 0$ with $f(0)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \lvert f^\prime(y) \rvert = \infty$. **Does we then have finite duration solutions?** This would give a very general case of finite duration solutions.

Comment: Thanks you very much for taking the time for this this interesting insight. I don't fully get the last part: you are asking for a finite duration solution with an discontinuity in the acceleration profile at $t=0$?, If this is the case made a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4389725/909869) and find that something of the form $$x(t) = \frac{(1-t^2+|1-t^2|)\,t\log(t^2)}{4}\,\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}\right)$$ could do that trick.

Comment: What I am doing in the last part is to try to generalize the case $y^\prime =\sqrt{\lvert y \rvert}$ to get a more general condition on which finite duration solutions exist. For this, I tried to identify what is specific to this particular example.

Comment: If is the generalization of a scalar autonomous IVP, is the first case studied on the papers by V. T. Haimo a cited on the question above... I am not sure if matched your definition at 100% (because of the $\mathbb{R}^2$), Did you review them? I recommend you to see first "Finite Time Controllers", since the other have an important typo mistake in an inequality sign.

Comment: On V. T. Haimo papers are shown required conditions, but I believe now that the two conditions I explain above are sufficient: if (i) zero is solution then $y''=F(y',y)$ leads to $F(0,0)=0$; and (ii) having a singular point $-\infty<T<\infty$ where $y(T)=y'(T)=0$ leads to $y''(T)=F(y'(T),y(T))=F(0,0)=0$, and since is singular there uniqueness could be broken, so conditions to stich solutions with the zero function continuously are met. Same can be done for the case $y'(t)=F(y(t))$.

Comment: Other interesting thing from the paper of V. T. Haimo, is that in her analysis she found that for the differential equation:
$$\ddot{x}=-\text{sgn}(x)|x|^a-\text{sgn}(\dot{x})|\dot{x}|^b$$ 
founding that if $0<b<1$ and $\frac{b}{2-b}<a$ then there are solutions of finite duration. Here, completely different from the **two conditions** analysis I did above.